# Update a datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am developing an app in which user has datagridview on display and he can edit the grid and there is an update button and it the user press the update button the grid should be updated. The problem is this how can I check that which row or column is edited and If I get whole grid then how can I get it from the display in the form of datatable for saving in database and what will be the query for database.

Comment: check [ASP.NET GridView control demo](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETGridView-5b16ce70)

Comment: All this stuff is built in to .net. Wire it up right, and you have to write very little code. Tutorial / book is the way to go. No way we can answer your question specifically.

Comment: I think you need to either change your `asp.net` tag to `winforms` or change your `datagridview` tag to `gridview`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On GridView_RowCommand:

We can find index if row through below code

```
int rowIndex = Convert.toInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

Now  we can find the row number from below code

```
GridViewRow row = GridView.Rows[rowIndex];
```